# class path resource [org/apache/ibatis/plugin/Interceptor.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist

Tags: spring-boot, mybatis

1. spring boot 2.0.3.RELEASE
2. mybatis 3.4.6

when I run project, point this error, but Interceptor.class can be found.

```html
<div style='background-color:#ccc'>
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [com.sankuai.xy.safelog.SafelogApplication]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/apache/ibatis/plugin/Interceptor.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
 at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:184) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:316) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:233) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:273) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:93) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:694) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:532) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:395) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1255) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1243) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
 at com.sankuai.xy.safelog.SafelogApplication.main(SafelogApplication.java:16) [classes/:na]
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/apache/ibatis/plugin/Interceptor.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
 at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:180) ~[spring-core-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:51) ~[spring-core-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:103) ~[spring-core-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.boot.type.classreading.ConcurrentReferenceCachingMetadataReaderFactory.createMetadataReader(ConcurrentReferenceCachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:88) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.boot.type.classreading.ConcurrentReferenceCachingMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(ConcurrentReferenceCachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:75) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:81) ~[spring-core-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.asSourceClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:734) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$SourceClass.getInterfaces(ConfigurationClassParser.java:963) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processInterfaces(ConfigurationClassParser.java:376) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:324) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:245) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:194) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:296) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:245) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:202) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:170) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
 ... 13 common frames omitted
</div>
```

project can not start, but Interceptor.class can be found.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7PWcM.jpg)

Comment: Having jar file on the disk (and even in IDE settings) is not enough. Jar file should be in the classpath of the application when you run it. Either jar is not in the classpath or jar does not contain that particular class file. How do you start the application? What is the command line and parameters for it? One of the common problems is that you don't use `spring-boot:run` so the classpath for your application is incorrect.

Comment: Thank u for your answer.
1.I use IDEA run application
2.idea -> project setting ->modules -> dependencies , have this jar, and I can find Interceptor.class on debug runtime.
3. I try to use command, application started!!   Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

springboot + mybatis
wrong pom:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
        <artifactId>mybatis</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        <version>3.4.5</version>
    </dependency>
```

right pom:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mybatis.spring.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>mybatis-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Did you check why it is wrong? Did you lookup what does it mean to have `provided`

Comment: yes, the question is provided. I meet the same problem , remove provided  can run, Thank you very much!